# Программируемые игры

Tags: разработка-игр

Хотелось бы попробовать поиграть в программируемые игры. Что-то типа "CeeBot", но немного посложнее.

Желательно язык С++/Java/C# или свой, но похожий на них. Так же желательно наличие графической составляющей, а не консольной.

Если Вы знакомы с такими играми, буду очень рад получить их названия или даже полезные ссылочки.

Comment: Еще http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colobot

Comment: Пока искал нашел Terrarium - игра от мелкософта, где нужно программировать живые организмы и "выпускать" их на интернет-сервер для теста выживаемости.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux-овский [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) - весьма интересный проект, предлагающий программировать танк на уничтожение себе подобных. Программирование на Java.